# Loading in files in order in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to load a bunch of image files for processing (to make a sprite sheet to be exact).  Thusly, I need to make sure those files are loaded in order for processing (otherwise the animations become all wonky).

The code I'm using is pretty standard:

```
    protected function onFileSelect(e : FileListEvent) : void
    {
        for each(var file : File in e.files)
        {
            var loader : Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.load(new URLRequest(file.nativePath));
        }
    }
```

I would have thought that because the loaders were running locally that they'd fire fast enough but no dice, the images are out of whack.

Any idea how I can solve this problem and load them in the order of the file open dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Who cares the order in which they are loaded, as long as you have them all loaded in the end? Afterwards, you can reorder them in anyway you want. For example, using an array to "save" the relative order from the open file dialog:

```
protected function onFileSelect(e : FileListEvent) : void
    {
        var loaderArray:Array = new Array();
        var i:uint = 0;
        for each(var file : File in e.files)
        {
            loaderArray[i] = new Loader();
            loaderArray[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loaderArray[i].load(new URLRequest(file.nativePath));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

When all of them are loaded (you can count COMPLETE events, as alxx said) you have the first image in loaderArray[0], second one in loaderArray[1], etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would take the approach danii suggested of storing the Loader objects in an ordered Array, another approach you could take is to read the loader URL in the complete function and then put the loaded image into your container (whatever it is) using that URL to sort them.

The idea is that you don't know what order they load in, but you can sort them into the right order afterward using the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use 'for each' you're not guaranteed any specific order as opposed to looping though each index in a collection which does guarantee order.

Also, there's definitely no guarantee that each load will complete in the same order you start. You'd have to wait till the first one completes before you start your second.

Answer (score 0):

Get your loaders in array in order you need, start loading and count COMPLETE events. When last one arrives, you're done.